# How to query mongo for every 4 hour for that day only

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to query mongo in node that will give result of past 4 hours only For that day it should give me count of result added 7:00 - 11:00 then 11:00 - 3:00 then 3:00- 7:00 like this.

I have tried writing different mongo query for each time interval. I want to make same query to run that will give data for past 4 hours.

```
db.CollectionName.find({"created_at": {
    '$gte': moment().startOf('day').toDate(),
    '$lt': moment(today).endOf('day').toDate()
}});
```

With same query to run. I want three different count i.e. one for 7-11am then for 11-3pm then for 3-7pm.

Comment: @zu11w Has it been fixed ??

Comment: @chyangba sorry for late reply. But it has not been fixed. the problem is I have to write single query that will get data for past 4 hours. What you suggested is different queries for every hour.

Comment: you want to get the result of the past 4 hours right??

Comment: Yes result for past four hours for different time interval from one query.

Answer (score 0):

Run this query to get the result based on the hourly basis for today's date

For getting datas in the interval 7:00 - 11:00 (7:00 to 10:59:59)

```
db.CollectionName.aggregate([
              {$project:{hour:{$hour:"$added_on"},title: 1,added_on:1}}, 
              {$match:{
                 hour:{"$in":[7,10]},
                 added_on: { $gte: new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)) , $lte:  new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(23,59,59,999))  } 
                 }
               }
              ])
```

For getting datas in the interval 11:00 - 15:00 (11:00 to 14:59:59)

```
db.CollectionName.aggregate([
              {$project:{hour:{$hour:"$added_on"},title: 1,added_on:1}}, 
              {$match:{
                 hour:{"$in":[11,14]},
                 added_on: { $gte: new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)) , $lte:  new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(23,59,59,999))  } 
                 }
               }
              ])
```

For getting datas in the interval 15:00 - 19:00 (15:00 to 18:59:59)

```
 db.CollectionName.aggregate([
              {$project:{hour:{$hour:"$added_on"},title: 1,added_on:1}}, 
              {$match:{
                 hour:{"$in":[15,18]},
                 added_on: { $gte: new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)) , $lte:  new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(23,59,59,999))  } 
                 }
               }
              ])
```